# Source plugin Nunit for TeamCity

Tags: .net, nunit, teamcity, functional-testing

Plugin nunit for TeamCity  uses its own build, where you can find the source code to recompile or another way to solve my problem?
 I added a simple attribute, it runs the test several times until it completed successfully. To test the web using selenium. Tests difficult, are sometimes fall. I would like to do without false alarms.
I would like to use it teamcity, that would not write a separate log for tests and writing email notification.

Thank you, Stanislav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using [nunit console](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.6) for running the tests?
So, instead of using nunit task in TeamCity you'll be running nunit executable with some command line arguments.
I suppose TeamCity could be easily configured to read the output from that console(it already reads it from some internal version of nunit).

Comment: is nice, but that this [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-14930#tab=Linked%20Issue) prevents to do it s